# Pickup words in text field - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data has a text field and I want to pick up the keywords in the list of: 'mr' , 'jr', 'dr', 'ii'
these words need to have space in front and at the end.
So with the data below, the output should be:

```
id|text|keyword1|keyword2|keyword3|keyword4
1, 'xxxx', 'jr','mr','ii'
2, 'xxxx','mr','',''
```

Thank you for helping.
HHC

```
Create TABLE have  (
    id   int,
    text varchar(225)   
);

Insert into have (id,text) values (1,'monday jr due date mr ii final');
Insert into have (id,text) values (2,'happy new year mr J');
```

Comment: What do you mean "pick up"?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX()` function within conditionals such as

```
SELECT id, text, 
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' jr ',text) > 0 THEN 'jr' END AS keyword1,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' mr ',text) > 0 THEN 'mr' END AS keyword2,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ii ',text) > 0 THEN 'ii' END AS keyword3,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' dr ',text) > 0 THEN 'dr' END AS keyword4
  FROM have
```

Answer (score 0):

First grab a copy of [Ngrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams).

Next you can do this:

```
SELECT
  h.Id,
  h.[text],
  ng.Token,
  Keyword = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.Id ORDER BY ng.Position)
FROM        dbo.have AS h
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(h.[text], 4) AS ng
WHERE       ng.token IN (' mr ' , ' jr ', ' dr ', ' ii ');
```

**Returns:**

```
Id   text                             Token   Keyword
---- -------------------------------- ----------------------------
1    monday jr due date mr ii final    jr     1
1    monday jr due date mr ii final    mr     2
1    monday jr due date mr ii final    ii     3
2    happy new year mr J               mr     1
```

A simple modification:

```
SELECT
  f.Id,
  f.[Text],
  Keyword1 = MAX(CASE f.Keyword WHEN 1 THEN f.Token ELSE '' END),
  Keyword2 = MAX(CASE f.Keyword WHEN 2 THEN f.Token ELSE '' END),
  Keyword3 = MAX(CASE f.Keyword WHEN 3 THEN f.Token ELSE '' END),
  Keyword4 = MAX(CASE f.Keyword WHEN 4 THEN f.Token ELSE '' END)
FROM
(
  SELECT h.Id, h.[text], ng.Token, Keyword = 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.Id ORDER BY ng.Position)
  FROM        dbo.have AS h
  CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(h.[text], 4) AS ng
  WHERE       ng.token IN (' mr ' , ' jr ', ' dr ', ' ii ')
) AS f
GROUP BY f.Id, f.[Text]
ORDER BY f.Id;
```

**Returns:**

```
Id   Text                            Keyword1       Keyword2     Keyword3      Keyword4
---- ------------------------------- -------------- ------------ ------------- ------------
1    monday jr due date mr ii final   jr             mr           ii           
2    happy new year mr J              mr
```